# What does xkill mean and do?

Tags: command-line, xkill

I found `xkill` on dashboard and my pointer turned into an "x" sign on clicking it. It doesn't change back when I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

What does this "x" sign stand for and what does it do?

Answer (score 22):

`xkill` is a utility used for force-quitting GUI apps. It is handy when some app isn't responding or is causing your system to work abnormally.

> ### NAME
>
> xkill - kill a client by its X resource
>
> ### DESCRIPTION
>
> `Xkill` is a utility for forcing the X server to close connections to clients. This program is very dangerous, but is useful for aborting programs that have displayed undesired windows on a user's screen. If no resource identifier is given with `-id`, `xkill` will display a special cursor as a prompt for the user to select a window to be killed. If a pointer button is pressed over a non-root window, the server will close its connection to the client that created the window.

To use it quickly you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and enter `xkill` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Alternatively, you can also type the same in Terminal. You can also define a keyboard shortcut in **Settings → Devices → Keyboard** to use `xkill`.

Your cursor will turn into cross sign and forcefully terminate (finishes the game (what I think) of) the app.

Comment: I have it assigned to a shortcut. Handy for killing unresponsive app windows

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy Added about that also :-)

Comment: A shortcut is perfect when you want to rage-quit a game! :D